# Как в Python забирать данные из потока

Tags: python, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток.
Нуждаюсь в совете , как одному потоку, забрать данные из другого, пока тот выполняется.(немного коряво, лучшей формулировки не придумал.)

Пока выглядит так:

```
import sys
import threading
import time

#Тут можно не смотреть, готовая рабочая функция!!!
# Print iterations progress
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█'):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = '\r')
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total: 
        print()

#Тут начинаем смотреть, начинается мой быдлокод!        
def long_function(): # некая функция, которая выполняется какое-то время, 
                     # по времени она не однородна
    n=0
    while n<10:
        if n<3:
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            if n<8:
                time.sleep(3)
            else:   
                if n<11:
                    time.sleep(1)
        n=n+1
        return n # собственно какой-то способ как отдавать на каждой итерации переменную
l = 10
t = threading.Thread(target=long_function)
t.start()
printProgressBar(0, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
while t.is_alive(): # пока функция выполняется
    t.join(1)
    # f = long_function  естественно это не работае.
    printProgressBar(f + 1, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
```

Смысл, есть некая функция, она как-то выполняется, хочу отслеживать её прогресс поитерационно. Нарыл на просторах, способ реализации прогресса.

Вопрос, как мне в переменную f поместить данные из выполняемой в отдельном потоке функции(пока она выполняется, а не когда она закончится)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import queue
import threading
import time  

def long_function(q): # некая функция, которая выполняется какое-то время,
    n=0
    while n<10:
        if n<3:
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            if n<8:
                time.sleep(3)
            else:   
                if n<11:
                    time.sleep(1)
        n=n+1
        q.put_nowait(n)  # собственно какой-то способ как отдавать на каждой итерации переменную


qe = queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=long_function, args=[qe])
t.start()

while t.is_alive(): # пока функция выполняется
    n = qe.get()
    print(n)
```

Comment: можно проще: `for n in iter(q.get, None): print(n)` и в конце `long_function()`: `q.put(None)`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработала и дополнительно разобрался с queue.

Answer (score 2):

Помимо очереди ([`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects)), чтобы связать потоки производителя/потребителя, можно обратный вызов (callback) передать:

```
def f(on_update):
    while True:
        ...
        on_update(n)
```

Пример из stdlib: [`urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) принимает `reporthook` функцию:

```
with TqdmUpTo(unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=filename, miniters=1) as t:
    urlretrieve(url, filename=filename, reporthook=t.update_to)
```

где `TqdmUpTo` класс [определён в документации `tqdm` модуля](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks).

[image: download-progressbar-tqdm.py's tty session]

Ещё пример [reporthook функций, реализующих текстовый интерфейс/tkinter GUI, c потоками/без потоков](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895723/4279).

Answer (score 0):

ну, например, объявите n глобальной в функции

```
def long_function(): # некая функция, которая выполняется какое-то время,
                 # по времени она не однородна
    global n
    ....
```

возвращать n соответственно не нужно.

вызов прогрессбара будет

```
printProgressBar(n, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50)
```

Answer (score -2):

threading лучше не использовать потому что это не многопоточность а шлак непонятный.

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def worker(status):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        status.value = i


status = multiprocessing.Value('i')
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(status,))
process.start()

while process.is_alive():
    time.sleep(1)
    print(status.value)
```

Comment: минус за непонятный шлак :), разберитесь в каких случаях стоит использовать threading, чтобы это принесло ускорение

Comment: с threading всё ок, если нужно делать I/O внутри тредов. Например в connection-пулах к БД. В целом, использование multiprocessing здесь может быть хорошим советом, если в треде идёт много вычислений. 
И про GIL не помешает почитать автору коммента, конечно: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock